# How to make an HTML anchor as clickable link in TTTAttributedLabel?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, uilabel, tttattributedlabel

I have an  ios application which fetch a piece of text from server and display it in a TTTAttributedLabel. The text displayed is stripped from a HTML.

E.g.

Original HTML

```
<p>
  Hello <a href="http://www.google.com">World!</a>
</p>
```

Text display in TTTAttributedLabel

```
Hello World!
```

However, I would like the word "World" be clickable as in HTML. I know that TTTAttributedLabel can be used like

```
TTTAttributedLabel *tttLabel = <# create the label here #>;
NSString *labelText = @"Hello World!";
tttLabel.text = labelText;
NSRange r = [labelText rangeOfString:@"World"]; 
[tttLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] withRange:r];
```

But if the word "World" appears more than once in the text, the above code will be wrong.

Can any one suggest a better method to handle this case?
Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution for this ?

Comment: Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally ends up using `NSAttributedString` to handle this. Here is my code.

```
TTTAttributedLabel *_contentLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] init];
_contentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
_contentLabel.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
_contentLabel.delegate = self;

_contentLabel.text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[[_model.content trimString]
                                                               dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                                      options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                           documentAttributes:nil
                                                        error:nil];
```

Also in my app I need to update the font size of `_contentLabel` on the fly. And here is the code.

```
NSFont *newFont = ...; // new font

NSMutableAttributedString* attributedString = [_contentLabel.attributedText mutableCopy];

[attributedString beginEditing];
[attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
    [attributedString removeAttribute:NSFontAttributeName range:range];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:newFont range:range];
}];
[attributedString endEditing];

_contentLabel.text = [attributedString copy];
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me as well..Thanks! I had a text from server that had the href tags...

Comment: If you are using swift it will give an error if you try to assign an `NSAttributedString` to the `TTTAttributedLabel`'s `text` variable. Use `.setText(AnyObject)` instead and everything will work as it should.